# Passing or accessing a variable in a nested function that is part of a callback

Tags: javascript

Hello I have the following code:

```
function outer() {

    try {
        ScriptLoader.getScripts('proj4script',proj4Callback);
    }
    catch(e) {console.log(e);}

    function proj4Callback() {
        x = proj4(some geo coord calcs here);
    }

    // I need access to the values stored in x here
}
```

As you can see from the code I load the proj4 script into my enviroment using a Scriptloader. Unfortunately this script loader has no return value. One of the arguments to the scriptloader is a callback function - this function can take no parameters.

I am trying to access data that I calculate intoside the callback function  in my outer function. Is there a way for me to do this that does not involve using a global variable outside the outer function?

edits:

@Trinot I am not sure what you mean by continuing the asynchronous call pattern, do you mean like this:

```
function main() {
    x = await new Promise(outer());
}

async function outer().then({

    await new Promise(ScriptLoader.getScripts.bind(ScriptLoader, 'proj4script'));
    let x = proj4(/*some geo coord calcs here*/);

    return x;
})
```

Comment: short answer? no. Why the aversion to uninitialized variables?

Comment: Can x be declared in function outer? It would be scoped to the outer function block and not truly global.

Comment: The values to `x` will almost certainly not be stored when the code at "here" is executed, since `getScripts` is going to be asynchronous.  You need to handle the "ready" event from the script being loaded in `proj4Callback`.  Essentially, the "here" code needs to move into the scope of `proj4Callback`, not the other way around

Comment: How do you call `outer`? Does the calling code need anything from it? Does the calling code need to be sure the script in question has been loaded once it has executed `outer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to embrace the asynchronous nature of the callback. So you should not try to code in a *synchronous* way. Put the code that needs `x` inside the callback, or call a function from within that callback that passes `x` to yet another function, ...etc. Whatever you do, you need to continue the execution from within that callback.

Now there is one other, modern way to tackle this: promisify the `getScript` method, and use `async`/`await`:

```
async function outer() {
    await new Promise(ScriptLoader.getScripts.bind(ScriptLoader, 'proj4script'));
    let x = proj4(/*some geo coord calcs here*/);
    console.log(x);
    return x;
}
```

This will interrupt the function execution until the `getScripts` method calls the callback, which in this case is the Promise resolver. Once that is called the execution picks up after the `await` statement, and can access the variables you need to calculate `x`.

Be aware though that the code that *calls* `outer` will continue to execute before the script is loaded. If you have also there code that depends on the loaded script, you must chain a `then` method to the `outer` call, or put that code also in an `async` / `await` construct.

Here is how that would look, assuming you `return x;` in the above function:

```
async function main() {
    let x = await outer();
    // rest of code that depends on the loaded script
}
main();
// Don't put anything here that needs the loaded script, as it will execute sooner.
```

Or else:

```
outer().then(function (x) {
    // rest of code that depends on the loaded script
}
// Don't put anything here that needs the loaded script, as it will execute sooner.
```

NB: You can wrap the `await` in a `try` block, like you had it, but you can instead bind a `catch` method call on the `outer()` call.

Comment: Doesn't that kind of defeat the purpose of using a script loader?  Maybe `.then` would be more appropriate?

Comment: The code that calls `outer` can continue to execute, and the browser can update, all before the script is loaded (depending on the script loader's implementation). `await` is syntactic sugar for `then`.

Comment: Thanks I was definitely thinking about the problem in a synchronous way. To be clear I am not using a callback by choice here. I need access to proj4 in my code and the only method of bringing that into the platform I am working on is via a ScriptLoader, and therefore via a callback. So in my case, the variables that I calculate inside the callback using proj4, are then immediately returned from outer() and used in the function that called outer(). I will investigate promises and aysnc/then/wait as I havn't had to use those in my js code before.

Comment: In that case you need to continue the asynchronous pattern at the calling side of `outer` and do `outer().then(function () { // rest of code })`, or do the same `async/await` trick there.

Comment: Your promise should resolve or reject, the one you wrote don't do that, error syntax.

Comment: @FernandoCarvajal, a Promise constructor callback can be written explicitely (with `(resolve, reject) => ...`) or can just be a function reference, which deals with that. I have done the latter, although `reject` is not called explicitly, but an exception in a promise constructor callback translates into a rejection, so that is OK. This is valid syntax.

Comment: Sure it can be a function reference, but you have to trigger the resolve, reject or whatever function you have pass... unless the callback execution that the async function have is the one triggers that. **Ugly way**

Comment: The `resolve` *is* triggered. It is the `setScript` callback argument. Nothing ugly about that.

Comment: Hi trincot sorry if you got a bunch of comment notifications, I was having issues with formatting. I updated my original post with a question.

Comment: See how you need to call `outer` in piece I added to my answer.

Comment: Yes I see now. Thank you Trincot this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Promises` like this

```
function outer() {
    var data = new Promise(resolve => {
        ScriptLoader.getScripts('proj4script', function() {
            var x = proj4(12312312312)
            resolve(x)
        })
    })

    data.then(x => {
        //You have the x here
        console.log(x)
    })
}
```

Or using the `async/await` syntax

```
async function outer() {
    var x = await new Promise(resolve => {
        ScriptLoader.getScripts('proj4script', function() {
            let x = proj4(12312312312)
            resolve(x)
        })
    })

    //You have the x here
    console.log(x)
}
```

And another solution declaring `var x` outside the callback

```
async function outer() {
    var x
    await new Promise(next => {
        ScriptLoader.getScripts('proj4script', function() {
            x = proj4(12312312312)
            next()
        })
    })
    //You have the x with data here
    console.log(x)
}
```